# Resolution (logic) and the cut rule

Tags: logic

If both $\Gamma \cup \{\phi\}$ and $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot\phi\}$ have closed expansions, how can one prove using resolution that $\Gamma$ has a closed expansion? Here $\phi$ is an arbitrary (propositional) formula, not just a literal. Can anybody provide a pointer to a proof? Many thanks!

Comment: What is a closed expansion?

Comment: @ Alex Kruckman. An expansion containing the empty clause  (terminology of  Fitting, First order logic etc)

Comment: Resolution is a proof procedure based on *unsatisfiability* (deriving $\bot$, the *empty clause*). Thus yes, if both the above are unsatisfiable, then $\Gamma$ is unsatisfiable.

Comment: @ Mauro Allegranza. What is sought here is a syntactical proof, not a semantical one.